# Python errors in Postfix Policyd-spf config: "warning: problem talking to server private/policyd-spf"

Tags: python, postfix

Implementing `pypolicyd-spf` support in Postfix 3.3.1 on **RHEL 8**, encountered following error in `/var/log/maillog`:

```
spawn[xxxx]: fatal: spawn_comand: execvp /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory
postfix/spawn[xxxx]: warning: command /usr/bin/python exit status 1
spawn[xxxx]: fatal: spawn_comand: execvp /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory
postfix/spawn[xxxx]: warning: command /usr/bin/python exit status 1
postfix/smtpd[xxxx]: warning: problem talking to server private/policyd-spf: Connection reset by peer
```

Can't be a path issue because user *postfix* has no path:

```
$ getent passwd postfix
postfix:x:89:89::/var/spool/postfix:/sbin/nologin
```

**Where do you fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### PROBLEM:

At first blush, appeared to be a  path issue, but it wasn't. ***Policyd-spf*** requires a **CORRECT** absolute path to find Python within ***Postfix*** in the `master.cf` configuration.

The path I initially had- *I believe I copied it from some HowTo somewhere on the 'net*- in the `master.cf` integration was:

```
policyd-spf unix - n n - 0 spawn user=nobody argv=/usr/bin/python /usr/libexec/postfix/policyd-spf
```

Was close, but no cigar: the path to Python supplied to `argv` didn't include the version number, so errors were being puked.

### SOLUTION:

**First**: Find where Python lives.  In ***RHEL 8.1***, I see:

```
whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib64/python3.6 /usr/include/python3.6m /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

**Second**: Supply a ***Correct*** absolute path to Python in the ***Policyd-spf*** config in `/etc/postfix/master.conf`:

```
policyd-spf unix - n n - 0 spawn user=nobody argv=/usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/libexec/postfix/policyd-spf
```

**Finally**, restart Postfix:

```
systemctl restart postfix
```

### CONCLUSION:

Don't chase your tail investigating path issues, and this isn't an issue specific to ***RHEL 8*** either. The fault will be buried in the absolute path to Python specified in the ***Policyd-spf*** config in `master.cf`